# Unable to interpret DDPG actor-critic loss curves

Tags: deep-rl, actor-critic-methods, loss, ddpg

I am training a DDPG actor-critic agent and ploting rewards and loss curves each episode to track the training evolution. Rewards values in the plot correspond to the total reward per episode divided by the episode length. [image: Link to image]

From the curves, it seems that the agent isn't learning much (rewards bouncing at about 0.50+ almost from the begining).
Also, I suspect the critic and actos loss curves are not correct. The critic loss shows a sawtooth pattern and the actor loss drops to negative values. I am not sure this is the correct behaviour.

As a note, I rescale the action output from the actor from [-1, 1] to [-0.03, 0.03] range. The action value that is stored in the Buffer is the scaled one. In the first implementation I didn't do anything about this when fetching a batch for updating the networks. Now, I undo the scaling before computing the losses but still the same results are obtained.

Does anyone have any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: to me the actor starts at around 0 reward, and then learns to get to around 0.5, which shows that it has learnt... maybe there is nothing more it can do(?)